Why doesn't prolog show false instead of all the elements related to a specific constant?
I have a program in Prolog related to a family tree, where i have to find all the sibling related to an individual.
I've defined the rule 'sister' as:
sister(X,Y) :-
    parent(Z,X),
    parent(Z,Y),
    woman(X)

Let's imagine 'Jack' has multiple sisters, Laura, Jessica and Julia. When I ask ?- sister('Laura','Jack') Prolog answers yes. But when i ask ?- sister(X,'Jack') it answers false instead of all the possible values of X.
Any idea of whats wrong or how to fix it?

What happens if you query ?- parent(Z, 'Jack'). ?

It showed one parent because I had the break clause (!), I deleted all of those and it started showing everything but multiple times, so I had to create new commands just to query stuff and not use the rules. I don't know if it's the best way tho.

I fixed it by defining a 'command':
consult_sisters(X,Y) :-
    findall(S,distinct(sister(S,Y)),L),
    member(X,L)

It finds all sisters of the individual Y, and add them to a list L once for each different sister, then Prolog will show every element X of the list L.

Rather use setof(t,sister(X,Y),_) instead.

Use intuitive names instead of X, Y, Z, e.g.: Sister1, Woman, Parent, Mother. Or at least more meaningful letters.
Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/78299706 - can use:
parent(alex, jack).
parent(alex, laura).
parent(alex, jessica).
parent(alex, julia).

% "female" is more general, covering e.g. babies
woman(laura).
woman(jessica).
woman(julia).


% S means sister, R means relative
sister(S, R) :-
    % Purest, most useful expression of inequality
    dif(S, R),
    woman(S),
    % Only need this to succeed once
    once((
        parent(P, S),
        parent(P, R)
    )).

Results in swi-prolog:
?- sister(laura, jack).
true.

?- sister(S, jack).
S = laura ;
S = jessica ;
S = julia.

